# simple css failed to load in the run

Tags: html, css, web, css-selectors, frontend

The below code is not working and I don't know why

```
<style>
    .gradient{              
        background:linear-gradient(#ffffff,#d3d8e8);                
    }

    .gridient .gradientcontent{         
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 980px;
        display: table;
    }

    .gridient .gradientcontent .worldmap{           
        float: left;            
    }

    .gridient .gradientcontent .worldmap .worldmapcontent {         
        margin-right: 15px;
    }        
</style>

<div class="gradient">
  <div class="gradientcontent">
    <div class="worldmap">
      <div class="worldmapcontent">
        <div class="worldmapcontenttxt">
          Facebook helps you connect and share with the people in
          your life.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spelling errors- you're trying to style a class that doesn't exist (.gridient)

Comment: My god, how I couldn't notice this.
Thanks for your wasted time.

Comment: @TripleM if it helped you, please mark his answer as solved.